# Is it possible to use 2D Array on Queues? windows form

Tags: winforms, for-loop, queue, multidimensional-array

```
Queue[,] inventqueue = new Queue[10,7];
for(int row = 0; row < inventqueue.GetLength(0); row++)
{
   for (int col = ; col < inventqueue.GetLength(1); col++)
   {
      if(inventqueue[row,col].Count != 0)
      {
      MessageBox.Show("Theres a queue on " + row + "," + col);
      }
   }
}
```

I have been trying this out but visual studio is giving me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're allocating only the double array, you still need to allocate Queues for each entry in the array like:

```
Queue[,] inventqueue = new Queue[10,7];
for(int row = 0; row < inventqueue.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = ; col < inventqueue.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        inventqueue[row,col] = new Queue();
    }
}
```