# 2D Array to Queue

Tags: c#, queue

Hi I'm having the following project to make a battleship game in C#,currently I made the game to work with 2D array of chars but my next target is to get ride of arrays and try to use as much as possible Queue structure for example how can I save all rows and cols into a queue ?

```
public void ShowBoard(char[,]Table)
int row,cols;
for(row=1; row<=10; row++)
{
   for(cols=1; cols<=10; cols++)
      {
         Console.Write(Table[row,cols]);
      }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use 2D Array on Queues? windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043822/is-it-possible-to-use-2d-array-on-queues-windows-form)

Comment: The page you talk about does not help me...